# Error in function deploy to decrease image size when uploaded

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to deploy a function to decrease the size of the image when uploaded in Firebase Storage.

This error is occurring when trying to deploy the function using functions written with **TypeScript**.

The function I'm trying to perform deploy is the same as the one below.
https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/image-thumbnail-resizer-cloud-function/

```
**The following error is displayed:**

λ firebase deploy --only functions

=== Deploying to 'myProject1154'...

i  deploying functions
Running command: npm --prefix "functions" run lint

> functions@ lint C:\myApp\functions
> tslint --project tsconfig.json

Running command: npm --prefix "functions" run build

> functions@ build C:\myApp\functions
> tsc

node_modules/@google-cloud/common/build/src/service-object.d.ts(72,45): error TS8020: JSDoc types can only be used inside documentation comments.
node_modules/@google-cloud/common/build/src/service-object.d.ts(72,45): error TS8028: JSDoc '...' may only appear in the last parameter of a signature.
node_modules/@google-cloud/common/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/oauth2client.d.ts(291,55): error TS1039: Initializers are not allowed in ambient contexts.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! functions@ build: `tsc`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the functions@ build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\LUIZ\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-01-15T15_00_31_114Z-debug.log

Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem a few days ago. You have to use the storage object from `firebase-admin` instead of `google-cloud/storage`

So my code looks like this:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions'
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin'
admin.initializeApp(functions.config())
const storage = admin.storage()
```

and then later

```
storage.bucket(fileBucket)
```

Comment: The error persists with the changes, in addition to the changes you indicated you need to run the command `npm uninstall @google-cloud/storage --save` so that deploy occurs without error.